# Can a conditional format be turned into a text outcome?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I want to be able to indicate whether a text is either referring to an AM or PM slot - at the moment, I have conditional formatting in place 'if text contains' - this is because the text only has some similarities in each cell but also contains a date that changes.

I want to be able to mark whether the session is AM or PM in a separate column - an example of what is placed in column C:
`Breakfast Club & Afterschool Club (2022/2023) - Thu, 08 Sep 2022, 07:45-08:30 session interval`.
The only part that remains the same is the time at the end.

I've included an image to show the type of text that is populated in column E - **in column K, I'd like for all yellow slots to be identified as AM and blue as PM** - but as you can see there's variation across days.

[image]

Comment: Why you need conditional formatting to do that. You can use regular formula to indicate AM/PM in adjacent column.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add input table and expected output table to the question. [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure. If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Comment: I've added an image to help clarify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked for:

> in column K, I'd like for all yellow slows to be identified as AM and blue as PM

Use the following formula in your `Code` column.

```
=INDEX(IF(A2:A="",,IF((MID(RIGHT(A2:A,28),1,2)*1<=11)*(A2:A<>0),"AM","PM")))
```

*(**Do adjust** the formula according to your ranges and locale)*

[image]

Comment: Perfect. Would it be possible to add a third code to this or is it limited to 2?

Comment: Glad I could help. Still. I fail to understand your new question @MatthewHarrison

Comment: Sorry, I'll try to elaborate. There is one other outcome in say column A which is when both options are selected e.g. an All Day slot. At the moment, the code picks up AM and PM perfectly - would it also be able to add a third code in column C to pick out those that have selected an All Day slot.

Comment: @MatthewHarrison First of all there is **just** column `A`. Furthermore, one could not answer that since I don't even know the text of the *"All Day slot"* in order to establish a pattern. Theoretically though, it could be done -once a pattern has been established- by maybe adding one more `IF`.